Problems with rendering reflections
I'm very new to blender and am currently struggling to get the reflections I want rendered.
So I have several objects and as a light source and surroundings I imported the city.exr using this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HIqF_MSnvU). I made the background transparent under render properties > film and was left with my desired lighting etc.
However when I tried rendering it, the reflections on my §-sign were not as they were in my render preview. I tried both EVEE and Cycles to no avail. As I needed to get it exported that night I simply took a screenshot (which is obviously not ideal).
Now after reopening my project the reflections can't even be seen in the render preview and I have the same matte §-sign as I did in my renders before.
Any help to fix this is greatly appreciated. I've attached screenshots of
how the render preview screenshot looked/ how I want the §-sign to look again in preview and in render,
how it is now 
and my material settings for the §-sign.
I'm really thankful for any and all help!
Aliena

Hello could you please pack your image and share your file? Only share the S object, use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform if the file is too heavy

The Roughness of your material appears to have been key-framed to 1. Is this a slip up? (Right-click > Clear Keyframes, if you don't want it animated)

Ah, that fixed it! Thank you so much for your help Robin!
